# Database Design for 36 Column Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some help with my database design for an application I'm helping develop. This application is a business tracking tool for dental offices. One aspect of the application is that each month the user will manually enter their office's Profit & Loss Statement and the application with track and graph the results.

The user will input up to 36 different items: Office ID, Income, Staff Salaries, Office Expenses, Advertising Expenses, etc. Initially, I was going to create a table that had 36 columns (one for each expense the user was inputting) and have each Profit and Loss entry be a row in the table. But I've been reading on database normalization and have read many places with people saying that that is an absurd number of columns. There are 10 offices submitting this data every month.

Are there any other ways to organize this?

Here is a sample of the code used to input the data. This doesn't contain all 36 variables as I've just been using this for testing. How ridiculous does this look?

```
'foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {   //get each $_POST as its own variable
        if (isset($$key)) continue;

        $$key = $value;
    }


    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO profitloss (officeid, date_month, date_year, production, collections, pt_refunds, other_income,
                                                       dental_supplies, labs, invisalign, rent_lease, utilities, janitorial, repairs, one800dent,
                                                       online_marketing, other_marketing, management_fee, merchant_fee, bank_charges, telephone,
                                                       office_supplies)
                                                       VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("iddddddddddddddddddddd", $officeid, $date_month, $date_year, $production, $collections, $pt_refunds, $other_income, $dental_supplies, $labs, $invisalign, $rent_lease, $utilities, $janitorial, $repairs, $one800dent, $online_marketing, $other_marketing, $management_fee, $merchant_fee, $bank_charges, $telephone, $office_supplies);

    $stmt->execute();'
```

Comment: Yes there are definitely other (better) ways, and indeed you should read up on database normalization.

Comment: Better suited at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for normalization usually depends on use cases of your database. Consider how possible is it that the expense list will change in the future, what kind of queries will you execute on your database, what kind of reports would you generate. If you really think you should normalize it, it's hard to tell the best way without examining your domain model, but here's one possible way to do it:

```
expense_type — dictionary of expense types
- id
- name

expense — a particular expense of a certain type for a certain user statement
- id
- expense_type_id — references expense_type.id
- profit_and_loss_id — references profit_and_loss.id

profit_and_loss — a single user statement
- id
- user_id
- office_id
```

If your database is designed in such a way, you can easily add new types of expenses in the future without altering tables or violating data consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make each expense or income as a column. Rather make it a row with transaction type.

This way you will have a table with less number of columns:

1. **Transaction type**: income or expenses.
2. **Tranaction category**:  Income, Staff Salaries, Office Expenses, Advertising Expenses. (income can be divied into many categories)
3. **Transaction amount**
4. **office Id**

This will make your design more flexible. if you add another transaction category you will add just another row not another column.

Comment: sorry less number of columns

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this,

have one master table

```
CREATE TABLE bill_typ
(
billtypid INT(2) ZEROFILL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
billtypnam VARCHAR(100),
billtyp CHAR(1) COMMENT "Either I OR E :: I for income, E for expance",
status CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO bill_typ VALUES ('','production','I','A');
INSERT INTO bill_typ VALUES ('','collections','I','A');
INSERT INTO bill_typ VALUES ('','pt_refunds','E','A');
INSERT INTO bill_typ VALUES ('','other_income','I','A');
.
.
INSERT INTO bill_typ VALUES ('','management_fee','E','A');
.
```

NOW Transaction TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE bill_typ
(
bill_date DATE,
officeid INT,
billno INT,
billtypid INT,
amount DECIMAL(11,2)
)
```